# android - how to keep watch on one value

Tags: android, shell, broadcastreceiver, android-service

The scenario is, I am developing an app which reads integer value from file and store it in integer. And value that I get from that file is always changing cause it is cpu frequency value.

How do I keep watch on this value from my activity ?
The ways in my mind are through broadcast receiver, service, observer etc.
But dont know how do I implement..

Comment: means you want to check value after some interval(time) ?

Comment: I want to check it constantly ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve this using chronometer tick listner. So on every tick of chronometer I read the file and set value to text view

```
chronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) 
        {
            //read file here and set the value to my textView
        }
    });
    chronometer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a listener:

```
public class CpuValueReader {
    private CpuValueReaderListener listener = null;
    int cpuValue;

    public void setListener(CpuValueReaderListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void startReading() {
    // this is an exmaple, you may read the file here
    // found value:
        setValue(theNewValue);
    }

    private setValue(int value) {
        if (value != cpuValue) {
            cpueValue = value;
            if (listener != null)
                listener.cpuValueChanged(value);
        }
    }
}
```

the interface:

```
public inteface CpuValueReaderListener {
    public void cpuValueChanged(int newValue);
}
```

Using it (just an example):

```
CpuValueReader instance = new CpuValueReader ();
instance.setListener(new CpuValueReaderListener() {
    @Override
    public void cpuValueChanged(int newValue) {
        // do cool things with new value
    }
});
```

Comment: It depends on your implementation.

Comment: I want to to read value from /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq. And value from this file changes constantly

Comment: So you need to constantly read it. I showed how to listen to this reader, not how to listen to the file change.

Comment: I want to execute startReading funtion again and again, any idea how to do it ??

Comment: Put it in a while loop. I suggest doing it from a thread, e.g. let `CpuValueReader` extend thread, implement the `run()` method, and in it call `startReading` in a while loop.

Comment: I tried like that in async task and also in thread , it is taking much of my cpu. and cpu value returning always max. Can I do it with onTickListner of chronometer ?

Comment: Yes , got the desired result :D Thx ,I will post answer immediately, and very thx to you, I got this idea in mind while discussing with u :D